# How do I get product variations in a preprocess function?

Tags: 8, theming, commerce

I'm trying to do something like this.

```php
function clientname_preprocess_commerce_product(&$variables) {
  $product = $variables['elements']['#commerce_product'];
  // Get the product variations and store them in $variations.
  if (!empty($variations)) {
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariationInterface $variation */
    $variation = reset($variations);
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_product\ProductVariationFieldRendererInterface $variation_renderer */
    $variation_renderer = \Drupal::service('commerce_product.variation_field_renderer');
    // Override the variation list price with the price of the variation.
    $product['variation_list_price'] = $variation_renderer->renderField('list_price', $variation);
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to get the product variations in `hook_preprocess_commerce_product()`.

What code should I use to get the product variations and store them in `$variations`?

Comment: An empty array is different from, for example, `[NULL, NULL]`: For an empty array, `empty()` returns `TRUE`, while for `[NULL, NULL]`, `empty()` returns `FALSE`.  This is a plain PHP question. It's enough to check that the value contained in `$variation` implements that interface.

Comment: Thanks @kiamlaluno. I understand the PHP part of the question. There is currently no value contained in `$variations` because I have no idea how to check for product variations in Drupal Commerce. So it's a Drupal Commerce question, not a PHP question.

Comment: `$product->getDefaultVariation()` gets you a variation to work with. `$product->getVariations()` gets all of them. Not sure having all of them will help you though.

Comment: Thanks @BWagner! In this case, I believe I do need all of them, so I can render the List Price field using the Commerce variation render service (rather than Drupal Core render service) to prevent AJAX from breaking. This looks like the info I need!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  $product = $variables['elements']['#commerce_product'];

  $variations = $product->getVariations();     

  foreach ($variations as $variation){    
      $list_price = $variation->getListPrice();
    // Do something with the variation list price here...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @quantumized! Actually the comment in the code was misleading; I don't just need the first variation, I need the list price to AJAX update when a product variation's radio button is clicked. Currently the Price does this, but the List Price does not.

Comment: You did a good job answering the question as it was originally written, so I'll accept your answer unless I get a better one, but I thought I'd give you an opportunity to make your answer more applicable to my actual situation.

Comment: @hotwebmatter - the code has been updated to show an example of looping through a product's variations and getting its list price.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks @quantumized, I'll let you know how it works as soon as I get a chance to try it out!

Comment: I accepted your answer! The client still has Twig templates that break the Commerce AJAX, but that is looking like another question. :)